# Check for a string 5 times over a duration of time

Tags: bash

I have this script here:

```
regex="WARNING\:\s+\[pool\s+www\]\s+seems\s+busy\s+"

tail -f /var/log/php5.6-fpm.log |
while read line 
do 
    if [[ "$line" =~ $regex ]]; then
        systemctl restart php5.6-fpm; systemctl restart php7.3-fpm restart
    fi
```

which basically checks for a certain warning in an fpm log and if it sees it, it restarts the service. What I want to do, however, is for the service to be restarted only if the warning appears 5 or more times over a duration of time (for example 1 minute). It should be fairly simple to do, but I can't think of the solution, does anyone have any idea?

Comment: Bash regex does not support `\s` shorthand. Try `[[:space:]]` instead.

Comment: Use a counter. Initialize it to zero before entering the loop. Add 1 to it every time you encounter a warning. If the counter becomes 5, restart the service.